# copying .png files causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, binary, binaryfiles

i am writing a function to copy binary files in C. The function works for all files apart from one PNG file.

Here is my code:

```
void copyFile(char* fileSource, char* fileDest){

    int *buf= (int*)malloc(sizeof(buf));
    if(buf!=NULL)
    {
        FILE *pr,*pw;

        pr = fopen(fileSource,"rb");
        pw = fopen(fileDest,"wb");

        while(!feof(pr)){
            fread(buf,1,1,pr);
            fwrite(buf,1,1,pw);
        }
        fclose(pr);
        fclose(pw);
        free(buf);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try checking for errors from `fopen` (i.e. add checks for `pr` and `pw` being non-NULL)

Comment: `int *buf= (int*)malloc(sizeof(buf));  ` eh... what?? `sizeof(buf)`?

Comment: Not related to the crash, but fread/fwriting one byte at a time is very inefficient. You should read/write larger chunks typically 64 k at a time.